# setting up davfs2 to mount properly

Tags: ubuntu, mount, sudo, nextcloud, davfs2

I am trying to set up my nextcloud account so that i can log in.  When I try to log in with sudo mount -t davfs2 ... it keeps on asking for my next cloud credentials - it does not get them from the secrets file that i created.

I have followed the tutorials online with the only difference being that the tutorials specify to update the /etc/fstab file.  But i do not want to do this because i have this set up on my laptop where i only sporadically have access to the internet.  I would prefer to use sudo mount.... and have the credential input automaticall from the secrects file (i understand that each time i will need to input my sudo password).

I believe that what is happening is that when i use sudo mount .... it is trying to load the system /etc/davfs2 configuration instead of my local .davfs2.  I believe this because when i try to configure the /etc/davfs2 (to point to my secrets file) i get config erorrs.  But when i purposefully put errors in the local .davfs2 config file the system never seems to recognise it.

the only other thing i can think to do is allow local users permission to run mount which i would prefer not to do.

What i may be doing wrong?

PS - using Xubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that your machine isn't always online you can simply use noauto in the fstab entry.

```
<URL> <mountpoint> davfs2 credentials=<full path to your cred file>,uid=<your user's UID>,gid=<your group's GID>,noauto  0       0
```

This will allow you to mount it with a simple command.

```
sudo mount <mountpoint>
```

And you can unmount it the same way.

```
sudo umount <mountpoint>
```

This will only get mounted when you specifically want, and never automatically on boot.